# How to optimize date time search in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, datetime, search

this is my basic date-time structure:

```
primary  key(datetime)         key
auot_id  date_time             user_id
1        2010-10-01 20:32:34    1
2        2010-10-02 20:32:34    1
3        2010-11-03 20:32:34    2
4        2010-10-04 20:32:34    1
5        2010-11-05 20:32:34    1
```

And I want to get the result of the `day(date_time)` at `'2010-10'` and the `user_id = '1';`
My SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM datetime WHERE user_id = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') = '2010-10'
```

but the `EXPLAIN` code display:

```
SIMPLE datetime ALL (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) 5 Using where
```

so ,this line of code doesn't seem to be very effectively。How could I to construct the table to make my search more effective??

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using a function on a column in a WHERE clause prevents efficient usage of an index on that column. Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM `datetime`
WHERE user_id = 1
AND `date` >= '2010-10-01' AND `date` < '2010-11-01'
```

Add an index on `(user_id, date)`.

Comment: I am new to mysql . So I am not sure what kind of index should I add on? I think I had made index on them:   INDEX `date` (`date`, `user_id`)

Comment: You want it the other way around as `user_id` is a "static" value, as `date` is passed to a function.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140693/39319 where user explains better how to cover all date and time periods if you are concern about midnight transactions

Comment: Functions or cast on the date/datetime column affects performance, and nullifies the index on the column (if you added index, for performance boost)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE datatime
BETWEEN '2010-10-01' AND '2010-11-01'
```

efficient and accepts indexing too.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
WHERE CAST(datatime AS DATE) = '2010-10-01'
```

Or perhaps

```
WHERE CAST(datatime AS DATE) = CAST('2010-10-01' AS DATE)
```

Would that be too inefficient?

Comment: This is just the same as DATE(datatime), which in effect nullifies the index